# Translator that translate from English to Pyglatin or from PygLatin to English

Tags: python, pig-latin

I am almost completely done with this program. Now I just need to figure out how to use tkinter to put this in a GUI but here is what I have thus far. Constructive criticism is always welcome.

```
another_word = " "
sentence = " "
new_list = [ ]


def global_reset(): #I had to do this function to reset the variables  because it kept adding the last sentence to the current sentence
    global sentence
    sentence = " "
    global new_list
    new_list = [ ]
    global another_word
    another_word = " "



#function to start the whole program over again if user wants to translate a new sentence
def again():
    again = input("Would you like to enter another sentence? [Y/N]")
    if again == 'Y' or again == 'y':
        choice()
    else:
        input("Press any key to exit")



def pyg_to_eng (i):
    global another_word


    original = (i)

    if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():
        word = original.lower()
        first = word[-3] #sets the last letter of the word minus the ay to the variable first
        word = word [0:-3] #sets the whole word minus the first letter and the ay to the variable word
        another_word = first + word #saves the first letter + the rest of the word to the variable snother_word
        return another_word #returns another_word to the input_state() function to be added to the sentence list
    else:
        print('empty')

#input function to translate a sentence from PygLatin to English
def input_state2():

    sentence = input("enter a word to be translated: ")
    list = sentence.split()
    for i in list: #for statement to cycle through each PygLatin word and translate it to English
        pyg_to_eng(i) #called the function to translate PygLatin to english for each word in the sentence.
        new_list.append(another_word) #appends each translated word to a list
    s = " "
    print (s.join( new_list )) #rejoins the list into a single sentence
    again() #function to ask if they would like to trans another sentence.




#function that translates English to PygLatin one word at a time
def eng_to_pyg (i):
    global another_word #global because it argued with me when I tried to do it without it being a global
    pyg = 'ay'

    original = (i)

    if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():
        word = original.lower()
        first = word[0] #saves first letter to variable
        new_word = word + first + pyg #seves word minus first letter then adds first letter and ay to the end of a single word
        another_word = new_word[1:len(new_word)] #deletes the first letter from the first of the word
        return another_word #returns another_word to the input_state() function to be assembled back to a sentence.
    else:
        print('empty')

#input function to capture an English sentence and translate it to PygLatin
def input_state():

    sentence = input("enter a word to be translated: ") #collects sentence to be translated to PygLatin
    list = sentence.split()
    for i in list: #for statement to cycle through each word in the English sentence and translate them to PygLatin
        eng_to_pyg(i) #function call to translate each word from English to PygLatin
        new_list.append(another_word) #appends each word to a list after it is translated
    s = " "
    print (s.join( new_list )) #reasembles the list into a sentence
    again() #function to ask if they would like to trans another sentence.

def choice(): #gives user option to translate from PygLatin to English or from English to Pyglatin
    choice = input("Press P to translate Eng to Pyg, Press E to translate Pyg to Eng: [P/E] ")
    if choice == 'P' or choice == 'p': #option for the user to translate     English to PygLatin
        global_reset()
        input_state()
    elif choice == 'E' or choice == 'e': #option for user to translate PygLatin to English
        global_reset()
        input_state2()

choice()
```

Comment: There are a lot of [good suggestions that @AChampion made](/a/145636/9357) on your previous question that you haven't incorporated.

Comment: Ok 200_success, I made a reply to explain why I did not incorparate those suggestions on that post you are talking about. And for me, doing the code on seperate lines rather then combining several on one line, just makes it more readable, which is a key factor of python. It is suppose to be more readable for the people reading/writing the program. To me, as a beginner, having them on seperate lines is way more readable. For all other suggestions from AChampion on that page, I explained my reasoning for how I did things.

Comment: once I learn more about python and have more experience I will probably do things like AChampion suggested but for now, a lot of it is out of my scope of knowledge. I am not trying to be an ass about anything, but I am proud of myself for figuring things out and writing a program that works.

Comment: Is "pyglatin" different than "pig latin"? If so, how?

Comment: Raystafarian hehe. pyglatin is a play on words by mixing python (the language its written in) with piglatin (the language its translating to/from)